# SQL Server: how to check securables

Tags: sql-server, security, sql-server-2005

I would like to make a t-sql query to check which logins have 'view server state' permission in server type securables. How to achieve this?

This query from mssqltips don't show this:

http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1718

```
SELECT prin.[name] [User], sec.state_desc + ' ' + sec.permission_name [Permission]
FROM [sys].[database_permissions] sec
  JOIN [sys].[database_principals] prin
    ON sec.[grantee_principal_id] = prin.[principal_id]
WHERE sec.class = 0
ORDER BY [User], [Permission];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check the server level permissions.  The query you have checks permissions at the database level.  You can achieve this by using the sys.server_permissions and sys.server_principals views.  Something like:

```
SELECT  pr.*
FROM    sys.server_permissions p
    INNER JOIN sys.server_principals pr ON p.grantee_principal_id = pr.principal_id
WHERE   p.type = 'VWSS'
```

See [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186260(SQL.90).aspx) for more information about the sys.server_permissions view.